# How to control Sidekiq workers RAM usage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

Ruby 2.3.0
Rails 4.2.4
Sidekiq 4.1.1

RAM of VM was 3 Gb and size of each of 10 Sidekiq workers was 250-300 Mb. Now I increased RAM to 5 Gb, but sizes of workers also increased to 500+ Mb. OOM from time to time kill one of workers.

How to control memory allocation size in this case, and why it happens?

Comment: Just wondering, why are you using 10 workers.

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady It's just for my experience) But even if count of workers is 5, they grow and grow... At this time they're 5 but size of each is 640 Mb.  Can't understand, how to tweak it.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think sidekiq is built to consume as much resources as available for performance, you'll probably find your CPU going way up, even if the queue is empty, I'll need to find you the documentation that confirms this.

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady CPU usage is around 20% and not depends on qtt of workers.